# Is it forbidden to build extravagant mosques?

Tags: masjid

What does Islam say about:

- Building huge mosques.
- Building overly tall minarets.
- Extravagantly adorning and decorating mosques.
- Decorating mosques with valuable metals or jewels.

??

Answer (score 1):

**On building mosques**

Building mosques is among the best deeds one may do:

> He who built a mosque for Allah, Allah would build a house for him like it in Paradise. (See for example [sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/muslim/55/53), [sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/30))

In one narration an-Nasa-I and ibn Majah added

> "Whoever builds a Masjid in which Allah is remembered, ..."

In another ibn Majah added:

> 'Whoever builds a mosque for the sake of Allah (from his own wealth) ...

Another version of this hadith in sunan ibn Majah says:

> "Whoever builds a mosque for the sake of Allah, like a sparrow's nest for Allah or even smaller, Allah will build for him a house in Paradise."

These ahadith show the importance of building a mosque and also what is necessary for the acceptance for that beside this one may read in the Qur'an another condition:

> And [there are] those [hypocrites] who took for themselves a mosque for causing harm and disbelief and division among the believers and as a station for whoever had warred against Allah and His Messenger before. And they will surely swear, "We intended only the best." And Allah testifies that indeed they are liars. (107)
>   Do not stand [for prayer] within it - ever. A mosque founded on righteousness from the first day is more worthy for you to stand in. Within it are men who love to purify themselves; and Allah loves those who purify themselves. ([9:107-108](http://legacy.quran.com/9/107-108))

**How the first mosque look alike?**

> In the lifetime of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) the mosque was built of adobes, its roof of the leaves of date-palms and its pillars of the stems of date-palms. Abu Bakr did not alter it. 'Umar expanded it on the same pattern as it was in the lifetime of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) by using adobes, leaves of date-palms and changing the pillars into wooden ones. 'Uthman changed it by expanding it to a great extent and built its walls with engraved stones and lime and made its pillars of engraved stones and its roof of teak wood. ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/95) and [sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/61))

It was anything but extravagant it hardly looked like any mosque now!

**On extravagance**

Allah the Almighty says:

> O children of Adam, take your adornment at every masjid, and eat and drink, **but be not excessive**. Indeed, He likes not those who commit excess. ([7:31](http://legacy.quran.com/7/31))

Even if we are recommended to wear our best clothes when visiting a mosque we are asked not to be excessive as is the general ruling in Islam:

> And [they are] those who, **when they spend, do so not excessively or sparingly but are ever, between that**, [justly] moderate ([25:67](http://legacy.quran.com/25/67))

Therefore the prophet () said:

> The Last Hour will not come until people **vie with one another about mosques**. ([Sunan abi Daowd](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/59), [sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/4/5) and [sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/8/2))

In his introduction to the hadith describing the first mosque and the expandation during the lifetime of 'Omar ibn al-Khattab in his sahih imam al-Bukhari also quoted the following statements:

> 'Umar ordered that the mosque be rebuilt and he said: Protect the people from rain, but beware of using red or yellow (for adornment) and distracting the people.
>   Anas said: They build mosques about boast about that, but they do not use them for worship except rarely.
>   Ibn 'Abbaas said: You are going to adorn (mosques) as the Jews and Christians adorn (their places of worship). (Source of the translation: islamqa #[97497])[11](https://islamqa.info/en/97497)

(See also in sunan [abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/58))

These statements should show that extravagance is not the goal of building a mosque a mosque in first place is a place of worship anything (any extravagance) that might disturb you during your prayer is frowned upon (or even haram) in a mosque (based on ahadith such as [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/34) in sahih al-Bukhari).